# How to end a user input array

Tags: c++, arrays, user-input

So this is for a lab assignment and I already have it working, but one thing is bothering me. The assignment involves creating a 1-dimensional array and then manipulating it. I am supposed to allow a max of 100 inputs but the user does not have to use all 100. Right now, I am using a while statement to either break or allow another input to be entered. To break the statement, you have to enter a negative number (this is what I don't like and want to change). What other options are there to end the user input, once they are done entering their numbers? Is it possible to end the loop once you hit enter with nothing typed?

I have searched stackoverflow for the last 3 days and found some compelling stuff but could never get it to work.

Note, I get the void function is redundant here but that's besides the point (unless it actually affects my ability to achieve what I want).

Also, thanks in advance.

here is my code so far (my while statement is in the main)... be kind I'm a newbie to coding.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverseElements(int array[], int size)
{
    int tmp;
    int j;
    int i = size;

    j = i - 1;
    i = 0;

    while (i < j)
    {
        tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    cout << "I will now reverse the elements of the array." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)    
    {
        cout << array[i] << " " << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 100;
    int iArr[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    int i;
    int myInput;

    cout << "Enter your numbers, then enter a negative number to finish" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)  //loop to obtain input
    {
        cin >> myInput;

        if (myInput < 0)   //checks for negative number to end loop
        {
            break;
        }

        else   //continues to allow input
        {
            iArr[i] = myInput;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    reverseElements(iArr, i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: you get undefined behavior if the first input fails (e.g. user writes "abcd" instead of a number) because it leads to reading an uninitialized variable `myInput`: `if (myInput < 0)` in your `for` in `main()`.

Comment: So an if statement to reject anything but numbers? I get what you're saying, but would this really have anything to do with exiting the loop for the array?

Comment: Please use @ and then nickname to answer somebody so they can get a notification. No, my comment was just a bug spot in your program: that's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @passing_through gotcha. Yeah I guess I didn't realize there was a difference between just comments and giving answers. I've literally only used this website for 3 days now and only 30 minutes as a registered user. Thanks for pointing out the bug, @, and answer/comment difference, I am now less noobish than I was before 

Comment: Glad I helped :) BTW, I've also offered an answer below.

Comment: Read your input one line at a time, using `getline`. That way it's easy to check if the user has not entered a number. The downside is you then have to convert the string returned from getline to a number. In general this is the way you deal with any kind of input checking. You read the data as a string, check the string, and only then convert the string to whatever data you want,

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution: let your user choose how many numbers to write before actually writing them.

```
int readNumbersCount()
{
  int const numbersMin = 1;
  int const numbersMax = 100;
  int numbersCount = -1;
  while (numbersCount < numbersMin || numbersCount > numbersMax)
  {
    std::cout <<
      "How many numbers are you going to enter? Choose from " <<
      numbersMin << " to " << numbersMax << ":\n";
    std::cin >> numbersCount;
  }
  return numbersCount;
}

int main()
{
  int const numbersCount = readNumbersCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; ++i)
  {
    // read the numbers etc.
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I wrote `readNumbersCount()` as a separate function to extract `numbersMin` and other "one-use" identifiers from `main()` and to make `main()`'s `numbersCount` `const`.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the main function a little bit.
Here the user is asked how many elements he wants to enter .
and doing the memory allocation dynamically so as to save space

```
int main()
{   int n=101;
    while(n>100){
    cout<<"How many numbers do you want to enter";
        cin>>n;
    }
    int *ptr=new(nothrow)int[n]; 
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << "Enter your number" << endl;
        cin>>ptr[i];
    }

cout << endl;

reverseElements(ptr, n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed and how does that answer the question ? Please, have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: i have asked user how many no he wants to enter , and doing it dynamically